# Master page in JSP files

Tags: java, asp.net, jsp, master-pages

I am new to JSP. When I used to work with ASPX I created a project with a master page, the `<body>` of the master page was like this:

```
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>        
</body>
```

and every ASPX file except the master had in the beginning `MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"` for example

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

and wrote only in `MainContent` like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent"  ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    code ...
</asp:Content>
```

Now I want to create same idea in JSP. How can I define the master and how I can define that the other JSP will be under the control of the master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this link: http://code.google.com/p/jsp-decorator/

You can have a decorator - the master - for the pages that you want.

I use an `xml` to define which page has which decorator, something like:

```
<decorator name="name" page="decorator.jsp">
    <pattern>/folderName/*</pattern>
    <pattern>/folerName2/*</pattern>
</decorator>
```

See the answers to this question: [Is it possible to define a decorator directly in a JSP with Sitemesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227123/is-it-possible-to-define-a-decorator-directly-in-a-jsp-with-sitemesh)